# Translation: 地灾

Tags: translation, meaning

We're getting 地灾 warnings over here...but what is a 地灾?

Apparently it's short for 地质灾害...

**adsotrans** dictionary defines it, word-for-word, as a geological disaster; which is pretty meaningless because who has ever even heard of a geological disaster?

**规范** writes:

> 地震、泥石流、地面塌陷、火山爆发等

but I mean, that is super broad and doesn't really tell me much - either there's gonna be an earthquake or a volcano is about to erupt...

Is there a proper translation for 地灾? (natural disaster? perhaps?)

and is it really that un-specific?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper translation is [**geologic hazards**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geologic_hazards). It is used to refer to any disaster that result from either human land use or natural [geological processes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aGeological_processes). Consequently, it is quite a large and, yes, unspecific, group of disasters.

In China, generally speaking it refers to one of the following:

- [Rockfalls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rockfall)
- [Mudslides](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mudslide)
- [Landslides](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landslide)
- [Ground subsidences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsidence)
- [Sinkholes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinkhole)
- Earth fissures

Technically geologic hazards can actually refer to many other phenomenons, but these are the ones usually meant when warnings and reports on `地灾` are issued. As you can obviously see, these specific disasters revolve around a similar theme. They are especially likely to happen after heavy rain. And so they often get referred to collectively as `地质灾害` in the press.

If the risk is actually a volcanic eruption, the press would probably spell out `火山爆发` instead of being vague by warning of `地灾`.

Comment: I just assumed being vague was in order to prevent mass panic.

Answer (score 1):

It is very common seeing shortened and generalized terms in PRC.

地震、泥石流、地面塌陷、火山爆发 ... --(generalize)--> 地质灾害 --(shorten)--> 地灾

Making things unspecified is some kind of trend, even in daily context.  For example, people write "建議" instead of 提醒/主張/敦促/呼籲/規勸/勸告/忠告/勸諭/勸阻/警告/告誡/....  and "選擇" instead of 惟有/不如/只好/寧願/寧可/情願/甘願/決意/被迫/故意/....  The more unspecified the harder it is to criticize or make judgements.

Comment: Sounds very diplomatic

Comment: Yup, another classical example is "rule of law" and "rule by law" .... both translated as "法治".